# How to use svg as Icon?

Tags: flutter, svg

I need to add new svg file and use it as Icon but I don't know how to do this.
In my project I have something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class PartyFinderIcon {
  PartyFinderIcon._();

  static const _kFontFam = 'PartyIcons';
  static const String? _kFontPkg = null;

  static const IconData person =
      IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
  static const IconData user_outline =
      IconData(0xe801, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
  .
  .
  .
  .
  static const IconData kalendarz_maly =
      IconData(0xe815, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
  static const IconData event_nowy =
      IconData(0xe815, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
```

but I don't know how it's working.

Then it's code it's used like this:

```
IconButton(
                  icon: GradientIcon(
                    customicon.PartyFinderIcon.event_nowy,
                    size.width * 0.0675,
                    LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      end: Alignment.topRight,
                      colors: colorGiver(0),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Or maybe I can add this svg as Icon in other way?

I tried with `SvgPicture.asset` but I got error that it's not type of IconData

```
IconButton(
                  icon: GradientIcon(
                    SvgPicture.asset('asset/path'),
                    size.width * 0.0675,
                    LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      end: Alignment.topRight,
                      colors: colorGiver(0),
                    ),
                  ),
```

```
class GradientIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  const GradientIcon(
    this.icon,
    this.size,
    this.gradient,
  );

  final IconData icon;
  final double? size;
  final Gradient gradient;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: size! * 2,
        height: size! * 1.2,
        child: Icon(
          icon,
          size: size,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
        return gradient.createShader(bounds);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share the code where you have tried `SvgPicture.asset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the class `GradientIcon`, you have placed the `Icon` widget (child of `SizedBox`), which expects an icon of type `IconData` and here in your code, it receives the kind of `SvgPicture`.

Remove the `Icon` widget and the `size` & `color` property, and specify the color property in `SvgPicture` widget.

Your `GradientIcon` class should return something like below:

```
return ShaderMask(
  child: SizedBox(
    width: size! * 2,
    height: size! * 1.2,
    child: icon,
  ),
  shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
    return gradient.createShader(bounds);
  },
);
```

and specify color in SvgPicture like this

```
GradientIcon(
  SvgPicture.asset(
    'asset/path',
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
  ..
)
```

Comment: Can I add gradient as a color to this?

Comment: I think that's not possible(not sure), in this case, have to check the plugin thoroughly.